Module not found: Can't resolve 'devlop' in '...\node_modules\hast-util-to-jsx-runtime\lib'
I'm trying to build a web chat app with React and getStream.io, and I get the error message in the title when I try to run npm start. This is after running $env:NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider". Before I switched to legacy, it wouldn't even compile if I ran npm start but instead gave the error message Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported. I'm mostly trying things in the legacy environment now because this way at least it tries to compile before giving me the error. I'm using PC and VSCode.
I tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling npm but the problem persisted.

"devlop" looks like a spelling error or typo. Check for discrepancies between "devlop" and "develop" everywhere: file names, folder names, script contents (e.g. commands, variables, parameters) etc.

Thanks for the heads up. I did check some places but all of them were "devlop" so I don't think it was a typo. I'm new to React but it also seems strange to me that something installed by npm would contain typos. Will keep checking though. I'd also like to add that the error in the title is followed by Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp' although I'm not sure if this is of significance.

Is there a C:\DumpStack.log.tmp, and if there is, what happens when you try to move it to a different location, and try again?

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything named DumpStack.log.tmp in my project directory.

@Eric did you find a solution?
